# AJAX not refreshing chat message section

Tags: javascript, ajax

I recently got a website aired and am having trouble getting the chat to work without having to have the user refresh the page (hence, the ajax). But the person on the other end still has to refresh in order to see the latest message. We're in the same room, so I can see if the chat refreshes or not; it doesn't, and here's the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var scroller = function(){
  posts = document.getElementById("posts");
  posts.scrollTop = posts.scrollHeight; 
}
var menu = 3;
var checksum = function(){
  if (menu == 3){
    document.getElementById('smileys').style.display="block";
    document.bob.smileyhider.innerHTML="&minus;";
    menu=1;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('smileys').style.display="none";
    document.bob.smileyhider.innerHTML="+";
    menu=3;
  }
}
//Chat ajax loader
var updater = 10;
function update(){
  var xhr;
  if(updater < 200){ updater = 200 }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
  else { xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); }
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status == 200){
      document.getElementById('posts').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  }
  setTimeout(update, (++updater)*10);
  xhr.open("GET","chatlog<?php echo date("d");?>.log",true);
  xhr.send(null);
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Have you monitored the AJAX requests using the Developer Toolbar or Firebug console and looked at the network activity?

Comment: I used firebug; it says, under the XHR tab (short for, xmlhttprequest i assume), it sasy 0 requests.

Comment: That sounds like your setTimeout function is not being called properly. I assume it should be constantly polling back and forth on all the clients every 3 seconds or whatever interval you have chosen.

Comment: From a quick look at your code it looks like the timeout is getting longer and longer. Try using a constant time interval just to narrow it down.

Comment: This article might be helpful [SetTimeout vs SetInterval](http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/repeated-events-timeout-or-interval/)

Comment: you just need to call update() once at the bottom...

Answer (score 0):

1. You are never actually calling update to kick off the ajax requests. I wouldn't nest it either
2. You want to use setInterval instead.  setTimeout will only run once.
3. I would just use a static value for updater, like 3 seconds

/

```
var updater = 3000;

function update(){
  var xhr;
  if(updater < 200){ updater = 200 }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
  else { xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); }
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status == 200){
      document.getElementById('posts').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  }

  xhr.open("GET","chatlog<?php echo date("d");?>.log",true);
  xhr.send(null);
} 

setInterval(update, updater);
```